# numpy nansum across first index

Tags: python, numpy, sum

I have an example 2 x 2 x 2 array:

```
np.array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 3,  4]],

       [[ 5,  6],
        [ 7 ,  8]]])
```

I want the nansum of the array across the first index as follows:

Sum all values in:

```
[[ 1,  2],
[ 3,  4]]
```

and

```
[[ 5,  6],
[ 7 ,  8]]
```

The sum of the first array would be 10 and the second would be 26

i.e.

```
array([10, 26])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this

```
a = np.array([[[ 1,  2],
               [ 3,  4]],
             [[ 5,  6],
              [ 7 ,  8]]])
np.nansum(a,axis=(1,2))
# array([10, 26])
```

because you want to sum on axis 1 and 2 only, and get one number per axis 0